# Database call returns undefined promise

Tags: node.js, sql-server, promise

I am trying to write an api that queries a mssql database. however my response from the api is always `Promise { undefined }`

```
app.get('/api/:year/:month', (req, res) => {
    var data = getData(req.params.month, req.params.year);
    console.log(data);
    res.send(data);
});

async function getData(m, y) {
    var query = "SELECT ...";
    sql.connect(Config, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error while connecting to database :- " + err);
        } else {
            var request = new sql.Request();
            request.query(query, function (err, rs) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("Error while querying database :- " + err);
                } else {
                    return rs.recordset;
                }
                sql.close();
            })
        }
    })
```

I'm assuming I need to await the result somehow as if I log the response inside the data function it is populated, however I can't seem to get anything to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating it a callback style function but not really taking the value. You need to convert it to promise based like this and use async/await

```
app.get("/api/:year/:month", async (req, res) => {
  const data = await getData(req.params.month, req.params.year);
  console.log(data);
  res.send(data);
});

async function getData(m, y) {
  const query = "SELECT ...";
  await sql.connect(Config);
  const request = new sql.Request();
  const rs = await request.query(query);
  return rs.recordset;
}
```